# Center Rust string in a number of characters

Tags: format, rust

I have been reading up on `format!` and all of the [formatting options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) and saw there was a beautiful way of centering a string of text using either `<`, `^` or `>`. Rather than centering a string in whitespace, is it possible to center it in a character?

```
{:^32} // Centers it nicely in 32 characters of whitespace
```

I was thinking something like:

```
{:^32'c'} // But this does not work
```

I have tried almost every way thinkable, except those that seem way too crazy. But luckily there is *Stack Overflow*!

Is it possible to center a string using numbers to achieve something like the following?

> --------SO is AWESOME--------

Comment: And so @Shepmaster is at it correcting my styling again. :-)

Comment: You'll find my hand in most every SO question in [tag:rust]. I strive to provide a uniform style and improve the grammar of every post, in the hopes of making each and every question and answer useful to those that come after us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to center a string using numbers to achieve something like the following?

Yes, kind of, as long as you truly mean "something like"...

```
fn main() {
    let s = format!("{:-^30}", "SO is AWESOME");
    assert_eq!(s, "--------SO is AWESOME---------");
    //             ^-- 8 here           ^-- 9 here
}
```

Referring to the [formatting syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax), here's the relevant parts:

```
format_spec := [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision][type]
fill := character
align := '<' | '^' | '>'
width := count
```

We specify a *fill* (`-`), an *alignment* (`^` / center), and a *width* (`30`). However, the string is 13 units wide, so to pad it out to 30 units, the fill has to be bigger on one side.

Comment: That works well for me! Certainly if one had a time they could make a method (or function for that matter), making use of your example, to always print out centered strings with the same amount of a given character on both sides. That should not be further away than a little flow control. :-)